# Stop 'downloadHandler` from executing in an ifelse statement

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating an app where the users can download the plot displayed. I want the user to be able to click download and ShinyAlert will pop up to ask for filename as the input.

So far the file gets downloaded if I press on save. However, when the CancelButton is clicked, shiny tries to download the page's HTML, with a "Failed - Server problem".

I placed an `if` function inside downloadHandler so that when `input$shinyalert != FALSE` the downloadHandler will execute the code, but I couldn't find the fault in my code. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Here is the code:

UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyalert(),
  plotOutput("vmgraph"),
  actionButton("downloadPlot", "Download Plot")
  useShinyjs(),
  ## hide the downloadButton and only display actionButton
  conditionalPanel(
    "false", 
    downloadButton("downloadData")
  )
)
```

Server:

```
observeEvent(input$downloadPlot, {
      shinyalert("Save as:", 
                 type = "input",
                 size = "m", 
                 closeOnEsc = TRUE, 
                 closeOnClickOutside = TRUE, 
                 showConfirmButton = TRUE, 
                 showCancelButton = TRUE,
                 confirmButtonText = "Save", 
                 confirmButtonCol = "#0075B8",
                 animation = TRUE)
    })
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      if (input$shinyalert != FALSE) {
      paste(input$shinyalert, ".png", sep = "")}}, 
    content = function(file) {
      if (input$shinyalert != FALSE) {
      ggsave(file, plot = vmgraph(), width = 12, height = 7.7)
    }})
  
  observeEvent(input$shinyalert, {
  ## Click on the downloadButton when input$shinyalert is updated 
    shinyjs::runjs("$('#downloadData')[0].click();")
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform your check for the cancel button before you get into the `downloadHandler`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyalert)
library(ggplot2)

gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot()

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyalert(),
  plotOutput("vmgraph"),
  actionButton("downloadPlot", "Download Plot"),
  useShinyjs(),
  ## hide the downloadButton and only display actionButton
  conditionalPanel(
    "false",
    downloadButton("downloadData")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$downloadPlot, {
    shinyalert("Save as:",
      type = "input",
      size = "m",
      closeOnEsc = TRUE,
      closeOnClickOutside = TRUE,
      showConfirmButton = TRUE,
      showCancelButton = TRUE,
      confirmButtonText = "Save",
      confirmButtonCol = "#0075B8",
      animation = TRUE
    )
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    # do not perform check here
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$shinyalert, ".png", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      ggsave(file, plot = gg, width = 12, height = 7.7)
    }
  )

  observeEvent(input$shinyalert, {
    ## Click on the downloadButton when input$shinyalert is updated
    # perform the check here
    if (input$shinyalert != FALSE) {
      shinyjs::runjs("$('#downloadData')[0].click();")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```